# Есть ли способы автоматизации создания мобильной версии сайта из нативного Android приложения?

Tags: android, html, веб-программирование, xml, android-layout

Кто-нибудь пробовал делать мобильную версию сайта на основе нативного андроидовского приложения?

Вопросов наподобие "Как сделать из мобильной версии сайта нативное приложение?" в сети много. А вот так, чтобы наоборот, мало что нагугливется.

Приложение очень простое. Типичные его страницы выглядят примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В частности, есть ли способ как-то, хотя бы частично, автоматизировать процесс создания веб страниц путем использования имеющихся layout'ов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Немного более основательно вопрос изложен на stackoverflow: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128269/most-automated-way-to-get-mobile-web-as-copy-of-an-existing-native-app

Comment: Есть такая тема как Android instant App. Суть его в том что, когда пользователь заходит на твой сайт и видит, что к ниму привязано Android приложение (которое офф зарегистрировано в Google Play) - он запускает кусок твоего приложение из маркета (без установки). В кратце пользователь открывает кусок твоего приложения в браузере даже не подозревая об этом.

Comment: Спасибо, погуглил. Интересная штука, не знал о ее существовании. Но как это имплементировать под мою цель я не знаю. Это, пожалуй, не совсем то.